# Qt Creator uses only 50% CPU on Build

Tags: c++, qt, build, clang, compiler-options

Win 10 Professional x64
Qt 5.15.5 msvc2019
Qt Creator 9.0.2

```
clang version 12.0.0  
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc  
Thread model: posix
```

[image]
[image]
[image: How can you achieve 100% CPU usage?]

CPU usage is about 50% during large project build after change processor from Core i5-7400 to core i5-12400F. How can one achieve about 100% CPU usage?

Comment: (1) right click the graph > Change Graph to > Logical Processors; (2) compilation is usually an IO bound task so maxing CPU is unusual.

Comment: @RichardCritten but Disk usage is only about 1%

Comment: Perhaps the build system produces enough work for like 6 logical processors ... therefore 4 of 7600 get occupied but not 12 of 12400F

Comment: Are there enough files to build that don't depend on eachother in order to utilize all cores?

Comment: @JesperJuhl yes, there are enough things to to utilize all the cores, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by specifying `Parallel jobs` count in the **Build Settings**.

- Rebuild subproject with `jobs=4` (average CPU load about 58 %): **time: 03:27**
- Rebuild subproject with `jobs=8` (CPU load 100%), **time: 02:18**.

[image]